# Error on line 21, column 5 of pubspec.yaml

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

#### Problem Description

I am trying to install http package into my flutter project, however I have no clue why I get this error

> "Error on line 21, column 5 of pubspec.yaml: A dependency may only
> have one source.".

#### File: pubspec.yaml

https://prnt.sc/riu011

#### Error

https://prnt.sc/ritzk5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have added the dependency in wrong place. The spacing/indentation matters.
The dependency should be in the same indentation level of the `cupertino_icons` and `flutter` dependencies.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  http: ^0.12.0+4
```

Comment: Arr I see, thanks midhun for your spontaneous replied.

Comment: Yeah, happy happy coding> :)